# Robotiq 3-finger gripper

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use robotiq 3-finger gripper in ROS. I install `soem` and `robotiq`. Then I

```
roslaunch robotiq_s_model_control s_model_ethercat.launch
```

in the terminal, but there is an error that could not initialize ethercat driver!

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'robotiq_ethercat::EtherCatError' what(): Could not initialize SOEM
[gripper_server-1] process has died [pid 2855, exit code -6, cmd /home/james/catkin_ws/devel/lib/robotiq_s_model_control/s_model_ethercat_node output:=/gripper/output input:=/gripper/input __name:=gripper_server __log:=/home/james/.ros/log/c63150d0-3c59-11e6-8c28-047d7b2de65e/gripper_server-1.log]. log file: /home/james/.ros/log/c63150d0-3c59-11e6-8c28-047d7b2de65e/gripper_server-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit shutting down processing monitor... ... shutting down processing monitor complete done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238324/robotiq-3-finger-gripper/) by [james](https://answers.ros.org/users/27270/james/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

Can you please confirm that you've looked at the notes at the bottom of [this page](https://github.com/ros-industrial/robotiq/tree/jade-devel/robotiq_ethercat)?

In particular:

1. I haven't had luck using the same port that runs ethernet traffic to do ethercat. I've always had to use a second ethernet port or card if my computer had one, or one of those USB to ethernet devices.
2. If you've covered the above, have you set the appropriate permissions ("sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep") on the actual executable?

Also note that the launch file has an option for choosing the ethernet interface using the "ifname" parameter arg. See the [launch](https://github.com/ros-industrial/robotiq/blob/jade-devel/robotiq_c_model_control/launch/c_model_ethercat.launch) file for more details.

Let me know if this works. If not we'll get to the bottom of it.

---

Originally posted by [Jmeyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26069/jmeyer/) with karma: 16 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [james](https://answers.ros.org/users/27270/james/) on 2016-11-29**:
Thank you it works

**Comment by [CharlieMAC](https://answers.ros.org/users/32694/charliemac/) on 2017-11-20**:
I have followed all the steps in order to control de Robotiq hand using Ethercat, even those that you mention in your answer. I have installed ethercat 1.5.2 from Etherlab following the steps of the manual, but I'm not able to start the EtherCAT driver nor SOEM.